# Android: Al girar el dispositivo mi aplicacion falla en mi fragment google maps. ¿Porque?

Tags: android, google-maps

Buen día.

Mi app tiene un fragment en el cual dentro, tiene otro fragment del mapa de google, funciona perfecto. Al girar el dispositivo de vertical a horizontal la primera vez , no pasa nada, la aplicación sigue funcionando, pero si en el mismo momento vuelvo y lo giro me sale un error, en el logcat me muestra lo siguiente.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
```

Y obiamente se sale de la aplicacion, pero no tengo idea de porque pasa esto.

El fragment que estoy usando para el mapa es este.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.com.mayorgafirm.saxtant.activity.MapsFragment" />
```

y lo estoy inicializando en el OnCreateView asi:

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    googleMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Que hay en la linea 28 del fragment layout?

Comment: linea 28 del fragment layout=>                                                                <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: Alli es donde se carga el fragment que contiene el mapa

Comment: Creo saber la razón podrías agregar tu código dentro de onCreateView!

Comment: El código de inicializacion ya esta en el onCreateView

Comment: mmm y tu código del MainActivity?

Comment: Por fin!! Solucionado. Quite esta linea en el onCreateView: googleMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState); Y quedo perfecto. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Ahora rota tu dispositivo y prueba si funciona.

Comment: SI, precisamente ese era el fallo, al rotar el dispositivo, ya lo probe, y funciona perfecto. Gracias.

Comment: @devjav, crea una respuesta de tu solución, así la podrá marcar como resuelta

Answer (score 1):

Por fin!! Solucionado. Quite esta linea en el onCreateView:

```
googleMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Y quedo perfecto. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: No olvides de marcar como correcta tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo tuve un problema similar, se reiniciaba mi aplicación cuando cambio de orientación, entonces debes colocar esta solución mucho más rápido en tu Android Manifiesto:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".NOMBRE DE TU ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Y Problema solucionado :) !! (espero te sirva :3 )